# UIView bounds from storyboard are not changing in code

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout

I have a UIView which has in the storyboard a `width of 250.0` and a `height of 135.0`. Because of autolayout the values should change when using different devices. But I always get `(0.0, 0.0, 250.0, 135.0)` whenever I try to `print(myUIView.bounds)`.

Is there a way to get the real value of the `bounds`?

Comment: try to use print(myUIView.frame).

Answer (score 1):

It depends, where are you printing them?  In `viewDidLoad`, they won't be adjusted for layout yet. In `layoutSubviews`, after the call to `super`, the frame should be adjusted.

Comment: You can use `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` in the view controller, too.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You need to do it this way:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() 
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

// put in your code that needs adjusted layout here

}

}
```